# Progress Bar, but NOT a Preloader or FLV Seekbar

Tags: actionscript-3, progress-bar, seekbar

I'm trying to create a progress bar to monitor the timeline progression of a loaded movie clip. Most of the tutorials out there are based on preloaders. While I get that the concept is similar, I'm struggling.

Users load various movie clips by clicking on a left navigation menu. I'd like the progress bar to show the users where they are in the movie clip's timeline. I'd also like the progress bar to start over when a new movie clip is loaded.

My progress bar is 508 pixels wide.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple really. You just multiply the total width by the percentage you are into the movie clip, so like this:

```
var clip:MovieClip; //set this to the movie clip that has been loaded
clip.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.enterFrameHandler );
var progressBar:Shape = new Shape();
var totalWidth:Number = 508;

function enterFrameHandler( e:Event ):void {
    this.progressBar.graphics.clear();
    this.progressBar.graphics.beginFill( 0x000000 );
    this.progressBar.graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, ( this.clip.currentFrame / this.clip.totalFrames ) * this.totalWidth, 10 );
    this.progressBar.graphics.endFill();
}
```

If you are referring to actual video clips (using movie clip in this case can be confusing because there is a MovieClip class), it is a tad bit more difficult because the `NetStream` class has no progress events or a total time property. You have to listen for the MetaData to be received which has the totalTime in it, which you would save to a global var. Then you can use the same method shown above  (using ENTER_FRAME on the container object, rather than the movie object) and use `( NetStream.time / totalTime ) * totalWidth` instead.

Comment: I don't want to draw the progress bar.  I have a movie clip containing the bar (seekBar.seekProgress).  Will scaleX work instead of drawing the bar?

Comment: Sure. Just set scaleX to `clip.currentFrame / clip.totalFrames` and you should be good to go. Do note that scaleX will completely screw with proportions (for things like rounded corners) if you do not also set scaleY. This is why I am manually redrawing the progress bar every time.

Comment: Gotcha.  The moving bit of my progress bar is actually a mask, so scaleX will work.

Comment: I'd like to include a marker image. A small image (5px wide), that would always display on the right edge of the progress bar. I tried adding this to seekProgress(), but the marker moves at a much slower rate than the bar: bottomNav.seekbarBtn.seekMarker.x = seekPercent*100;

Comment: Position it the same way as you set the scaleX. `seekMarker.x = clip.currentFrame / clip.totalFrames * totalWidth`.

Comment: This worked for the marker:  seekMarker.x = (seekProgress.x + seekProgress.width)